# Django Allauth - New user type using default Signup form with other forms

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-authentication, django-allauth

I have created a seller app which allows sellers to apply for a seller account. I am using allauth signup form and 2 other custom forms for collecting information apart from username, email and password (collected by allauth signup form). The other info that I need has Seller Name, Mobile number etc. and also collects seller address.

I have a class based form view created and these views captures Seller info and Adresss info but I do not know how to send the signup information to create the new (seller) via allauth. How can I create the user within seller account apply view?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? If so, could you share?

Comment: @Ryan yes I did I will post a reply tomorrow for you. hope that's ok